# How can i add arrows like this in the between of the circles in a website

Tags: javascript, html, css

[How can i make it look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUFQM.png)

I want to make lines with arrow head in between the circles pointing to another circle on its right.

I've added the text inside of the circle and outside the circle but I'm unable to create arrows in between the circle

The best I could do can be seen below, also its not responsive.

```css
.circle{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    text-align: center;
}
.arrow-line{
    width: 300px;
    height: 1px; 
    border: 1px #0070BA solid;
    margin-top: 55px;
}
.arrow {
    width: 10px;
    border: solid #0070BA ;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.right {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.circletext{
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 800;
    line-height: 29px;
    letter-spacing: 0.03em;
    text-align: left;
    color: #595555;
}
.circle-1 {
    background-color:#fff;
    border:2px solid #0070BA;    
    height:69px;
    width: 65px;;
    border-radius:50%;
    color: #0070BA;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="circletext">
    <div class="circle-1">1</div>Planning
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-line"></div>
  <p>
    <i class="arrow right"></i>
  </p>
  <div class="circletext">
    <div class="circle-1">2</div>Recruit
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-line"></div>
  <p>
    <i class="arrow right"></i>
  </p>
  <div class="circletext">
    <div class="circle-1">3</div>Training and <br>Collaboration
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-line"></div>
  <p>
    <i class="arrow right"></i>
  </p>
  <div class="circletext">
    <div class="circle-1">4</div>Support
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: without changing the markup, it will be a battle

Comment: `not responsive.`   How do you want it to be responsive, if you it's just scale to fit, an SVG would work well here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You deffinitely need to change markup, so that the arrows were dependant on the elements they are connecting/ Something like this

```css
.circle{
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
    align-items: flex-start;
    text-align: center;
}

.circletext{
  position: relative;
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 800;
    line-height: 29px;
    letter-spacing: 0.03em;
    text-align: left;
    color: #595555;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  
  
}
.circletext:not(:last-child)::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% + 40px);
  top: 50px;
  height: 2px;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  background-color: red;
}

.circletext:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(150% - 60px);
  top: 42px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border: solid red;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.circle-1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:2px solid #0070BA;    
    height:70px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius:50%;
    color: #0070BA;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="circletext">
    <div class="circle-1">1</div>Planning
  </div>
  <div class="circletext">
    <div class="circle-1">2</div>Recruit
  </div>
  <div class="circletext">
    <div class="circle-1">3</div>Training and <br>Collaboration
  </div>
  <div class="circletext">
    <div class="circle-1">4</div>Support
  </div>
</div>
```